# Is the light emitted by a laser a 'beam' or a 'ray'?

Tags: optics, terminology, laser, structural-beam

In English, the light generated by a laser is almost always referred to in technical texts as a 'laser beam'.

However, in French, Spanish, Portuguese and Italian, forms that correspond to *laser beam* and *laser ray* are both used seemingly interchangeably (see [the terms recommended on IATE, the EU's inter-institutional terminology database](http://iate.europa.eu/SearchByQuery.do?method=search&query=laser%20beam&sourceLanguage=en&&targetLanguages=de&targetLanguages=en&targetLanguages=es&targetLanguages=fr&targetLanguages=it&targetLanguages=pt&domain=0&matching=&typeOfSearch=s&start=20&next=1)).

Here are a few examples from IATE:

**EN**
laser beam

**ES**
rayo láser (literally: laser ray)
haz lasérico (literally: laser beam)

**FR**
rayon laser (literally: laser ray)
faisceau laser (literally: laser beam)

Is the use of an equivalent to *beam* in Romance language less technically  accurate than the convention in English?

Is the light emitted by a laser a 'beam' or a 'ray', or possibly both?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a linguistic question about Romance languages rather than a question about physics itself.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback RedGrittyBrick. As I see it, this is a question about the most appropriate nomenclature for a phenomenon in physics (regardless of language) with numerous examples of inconsistency from a recognised resource. 

This inconsistency might be down to a lack of technical accuracy, or it might be because both descriptions are valid. I'd therefore characterize this as a question regarding the concept of a 'laser beam' motivated by inconsistent use of language rather than a question about language.

Comment: If it is usually called a 'beam' in English *then that's the correct term in English*: if it was normally called a 'Hund' in German then *that would be the correct term in German*.  Natural languages are defined by their speakers (and writers to a lesser extent, although this may be more significant in scientific language).  This is not a question about physics but one which seems to be based on a misunderstanding of the nature of natural languages.

Comment: I appreciate your input tfb. I agree with your statements but I don't believe them to be applicable here.

Firstly, this is specifically a question regarding scientific language, not general language. Secondly, this is not a question of consistency between English and French, but whether the same consistency seen in scientific language in English when discussing the language-independent concepts labelled as *beams* and *rays* would be appropriate in French, Spanish, Italian and other languages.

Comment: @tfb I appreciate however that this was not clear without the examples that I've now added.

Answer (score 2):

[In optics a "ray"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_optics) is the direction of propagation of the classical electromagnetic wave.

The term "ray' used for particles, as "cosmic rays" , and "gamma rays" are associated with this directional definition, from the times when it was clear that the phenomena followed straight lines like optical rays, before the differentiation into the particles we know now.

It is reasonable that the term "ray" as well as "radiation" will take different nuances in different countries.

Beam is used for bunches of particles in english, too,  "a beam of protons", but its original meaning came as a "beam of light", so it is reasonable to call the laser rays "beam of light".

Answer (score 0):

Light is an electromagnetic wave. And for example gamma rays are electromagnetic waves. So the visible and near-visible light produced by most laser is like gamma rays but with a different frequency (wavelength). Thus saying ray and beam is roughly the same. Scientific convention is to say laser beam when the emitted electromagnetic waves are strongly directional and to say ray when there is no definition of the direction (it may either be non-directional or directional). So it looks like that in romance languages it is less technically accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Regarding directionality, are you referring specifically to the context of lasers, or more to optics in general?

Comment: To optics in general. I'd say anything strongly directional is a beam.

Answer (score 0):

Lasers are termed as beam. Maybe the reason behind this terminology is the finite and easily characterizable size of the laser. Laser can propagate in a in a defined direction without diverging appreciably, on the other hand the term ray refer to something that propagate in a straight line.  However, the parallelism is not necessary property.

Comment: Thanks hsinghal. Lasers are termed as beam *in English*. However, the convention for other languages does not seem to be as established. Do you mean to say that rays diverge when propagating in a straight line, and beams do not appreciably do so?

Comment: @PrettyHands Yes, but these definitions are not very hard and fast.